# How to set custom visible range in timeline view with working prev/next periods in Fullcalendar v4?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

How can I set custom visible range in timeline view in Fullcalendar? I am able to set it, but arrows to next or previous ranges are not working then.

I use this code and FC shows me date range `2020-08-01 - 2020-09-30` correctly after loading. But when I click previous/next arrow at the top of FC to move to another period, nothing happend. Why? `Validrange` is long enought.

My goal is, if visible range is set like example above (two months), next period should be `2020-10-01 - 2020-11-30` (two months), previous period should be the same. But visibe range can be different, it is selected by user.

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar'), {
  defaultView: 'resourceTimeline',

  /*
  defaultView: 'resourceTimeline30',
  views: {
    resourceTimeline30: {
      type: 'resourceTimeline',
      duration: {
        days: 30
      }
    }
  },
  */

  firstDay: 1,
  slotWidth: 22,
  snapDuration: '12:00',
  slotDuration: '12:00',
  slotLabelInterval: '24:00',
  slotLabelFormat: [{ weekday: 'short', day: 'numeric', month: 'long' }],
  validRange: {
    start: '2019-08-14',
    end: '2021-08-13'
  },
  visibleRange: function(currentDate) {
    var startDate = new Date(currentDate.valueOf());
    var endDate = new Date(currentDate.valueOf());

    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 30);
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 30);

    return { start: startDate, end: endDate };
  }
});
```

Comment: Currently your range is static - it only ever covers the dates shown. You need to make your range dynamic by specifying the visibleRange as a callback function, as per the example in the documentation - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/visibleRange

Comment: You're right, but I'm not sure, if I understand how the callback function works. It operates with `currentDate`, but in example above, when I click first time to prev, I get `2020-08-12`, when I click again to prev I still get `2020-08-12` (the same with next arrow, I get `2020-08-14`). Shoud not I get `2020-08-11` instead? I do not know how I can set `visibleRange` from `2020-07-01` to `2020-08-31` (at the beginning, while loading) and then skip to previous 60 days when I pres prev arrow and the same when I click the next arrow?

Comment: I think that might be because of your validRange settings. fullCalendar won't let you navigate outside the valid range, if I remember correctly

Comment: I use valid range -365 days in the past and +365 in the future, as I wrote above. I think this should not be the reason.

Comment: Ok. Please show the code you've written for your visibleRange function so far, then I can understand more clearly where you're getting stuck. You basically need to take the currentDate you're given, and calculate what the date would be 60 days before that, and 60 days afterwards, and then use those as the start and end dates to return

Comment: P.S. Instead of visible range, did you just try setting a "duration" value instead? E.g. you could try setting it to a fixed number of days, or maybe as 2 months, instead. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/duration . It's probably simpler.

Comment: I edited my code in question post. I've tried only their example code, because I've got the wierd results in `currentDate` like I wrote and I have no idea how to solve it in my case.

Comment: To clarify it, I use `duration` in another view of FC - if user want to show certain number of days from today, I use `duration` (I added it in my code above, it is commented). But I want to give user chance to select specific date range and that is the problem with `duration`, because it shows certain number of days only from today (I did not find any option to set the start day in documentation).

Comment: I haven't tested it fully but it seems to work better if you set a value for dateIncrement: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/zYvRNGq (docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/dateIncrement)

Comment: Well, prev arrow somehow works, but next arrow does not. I still get only next day (15th of Aug today) when I press it repeatedly. Could not be problem with custom settings in `slotDuration` and `slotLabelInterval`, because I do not use whole day, but "halfdays", becuase I need to move events view half of day?

Comment: Maybe I've found a working solution - `defaultDate` allows me to set a specific date as a start date of FC. Then I can set via `duration` number of days user want to display (calculated as difference between start and end date from user choice). In this case prev and next arrows seem to work.

Comment: Ok that sounds interesting. If you're happy with it, please do add the code (and a brief description) as an answer below so that others (including me!) can learn from it.